# Select from 2 table and get 1 result of table_2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 table, table 2 contains many addresses of shop. Table 2 references with table 1 by Shop_ID
I want to select like that [see image]
please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `row_number()`:

```
select shop_id, 
  shop_name,
  shop_address
from
(
  select t1.shop_id,
    t1.shop_name,
    t2.shop_address,
    row_number() over(partition by t1.shop_id
                      order by t1.shop_name, t2.shop_address) rn
  from table_1 t1
  inner join table_2 t2
    on t1.shop_id = t2.shop_id
) src
where rn = 1
```

See a [demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32a6e/2)

You can also use an aggregate function:

```
select t1.shop_id, 
  t1.shop_name,
  max(t2.shop_address) shop_address
from Table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.shop_id = t2.shop_id
group by t1.shop_id, t1.shop_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32a6e/6)

Comment: thanks for your answer, problem is solved :)), thank you very much :)

Comment: but row_number() over(partition) cannot convert to linq, linq do not support row_number() :(